# THREE.js unable to cast shadows on to a plane from simple cube

Tags: three.js, shadow, cube, plane

I am rather new to Three.js but I just can't see why this isn't working. I have a very simple scene; a cube on a plane with a spotlight. I want there to be a shadow cast upon the plane from the cube.  The cube and plane render fine but the shadow is not appearing.

Here is the failed attempt:
http://www.owensouthwood.com/experiments/cubething/

I am expecting a shadow to appear on the floor to the lower right hand side of the cube.

And here is the `init()` function which as you can see includes lines to ensure that `castShadow=true` and `receiveShadow=true`  - what else do I need?

```
function init() {
            // create new scene
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            // setup renderer
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1.0); 
            renderer.setSize(W,H);
            renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

            // setup camera pointing at scene
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, W/H, 0.1 , 10000);
            camera.position.x = 1;
            camera.position.y = 1;
            camera.position.z = 1;
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);

            // draw a cube
            var cubeWidth = 0.5;
            var cubeHeight = 0.5;
            var cubeDepth = 0.5;            
            var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(cubeWidth, cubeHeight, cubeDepth);
            var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: "yellow", ambient: "white", shininess: 9, metal: true, reflectivity: 9 });                
            cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
            // make the cube cast and recieve shadow
            cube.castShadow = true;
            cube.receiveShadow = true;            
            scene.add(cube);

            // draw a floor (plane) for the cube to sit on 
            var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 20);
            var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: "white" });  
            var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
            // make the plane recieve shadow from the cube
            plane.receiveShadow = true;
            plane.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
            plane.position.y = -2;
            scene.add(plane);

            // add a spotlight to illuminate the cube and cause shadows            
            var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
            spotLight.position.set(1, 2, 2);
            spotLight.castShadow = true; 
            spotLight.intensity = 1;
            scene.add(spotLight);

            // render it!
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            render();

        }
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Thanks
Owen

Comment: this should help: http://jsfiddle.net/4Txgp/13/

Answer (score -1):

Solved - although I'm not sure it is the proper way to solve it, it seems that adding the following line to my spotlight definition fixes the problem:

```
spotLight.shadowCameraNear = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use following line
`spotLight.shadowCameraNear = 1;`
since `.shadowCameraNear` accepts number so it can't be used as boolean

Comment: What does `true` evaluate to in Javascript?